# Debian listing packages that are recommended by already installed packages

Tags: debian, package-management

As the tittle suggests: I'm looking for a way to list every package that is recommended by one of the packages that are already installed on my system. Kinda similarly to how `apt` displays recommended packages when installing something.
I'd prefer to have the list as `X package recommends: W,Y,Z packages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
dpkg-query -W -f \
  '${db:Status-Abbrev} ${Package} package recommends ${Recommends} packages\n' |
  sed -nr '/( [^ ]+){5,}/ s/^.i. //p'
```

Answer (score 1):

However the following code generate duplicate data, but for start point is good point:

```
dpkg -l "*" |egrep ^ii |awk {'print $2'} | xargs  apt-cache show |egrep ^Recomm
```

You should same thing in a loop:

```
pack=`dpkg -l "*" |egrep ^ii |awk {'print $2'}`
echo ${pack}:`apt-cache show $pack|egrep ^Recomm`
```